# namespace "asio" has no member "io_context"

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

I am trying figure out why it is saying this when a video I am following I did the exact same thing but it works for him. The error I am trying to solve is namespace "asio" has no member "io_context"
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HB0Z.png)

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#endif
#define ASIO_STANDALONE // asio came out of the boost development framework but
// I am not using it so it tells asio it should be used as standalone.
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/ts/buffer.hpp> // Handle the movement of memory
#include <asio/ts/internet.hpp> // Prepares asio for all the things I need to do network communication

int main()
{
    asio::error_code ec;

    // Create a "context" - essentially the platform specific interface
    asio::io_context context;

    // Get address of where I want to connect to
    asio::ip:tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1", ec), 80);

    // Create a socket, the context will deliver the implementation
    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(context);

    // Tell socket to connect to address
    socket.connect(endpoint, ec);

    // Checks for connection status (Connected/Failed)
    if (!ec) {
        std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect to:\n" << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your first compilation error please, verbatim, and in its entirety?

Comment: `io_context` still appears to be in the `boost::asio` namespace, whether you're using it standalone or not. Why are you leaving off `boost`?

Comment: Also please specify which version of boost or asio you're using.

Comment: you need `#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>`

Answer (score 1):

Your version of boost uses the old interface (`io_service`). Just upgrade or use the old interface.

Comparison and upgrade instructions: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html

Here's your snippet under Boost 1.66:

**[Live Om Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QvLuTnADHRUN9ys8)**

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#endif
#define ASIO_STANDALONE // asio came out of the boost development framework but
// I am not using it so it tells asio it should be used as standalone.
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;

int main() {
    error_code ec;
    asio::io_service context;
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1", ec), 80);

    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(context);
    socket.connect(endpoint, ec);

    if (!ec) {
        std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect to:\n" << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Connected!
```

---

### More Modern:

Using Boost 1.73

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cGEKrPNWaPdV4SWU)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    try {
        tcp::socket socket(boost::asio::system_executor{});
        socket.connect({{}, 80});

        std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect to:\n" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Also prints "Connected!". (Unless of course on wandbox)

Comment: Added an "old fashioned 1.66.0" version as well as a much simplified 1.73.0 version. [Live demos]